# Cannot get pandas to open CSV [Python, Jupyter, Pandas]

Tags: python, csv, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

**OBJECTIVE**

Using Jupyter notebooks, import a csv file for data manipulation

**APPROACH**

1. Import necessary libraries for statistical analysis (pandas, matplotlib, sklearn, etc.)
2. **Import data set using pandas**
3. Manipulate data

**CODE**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
style.use("ggplot")

import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

data = pd.read_csv("../data/walmart-stores.csv")

print(data)
```

**ERROR**

```
OSError: File b'../data/walmart-stores.csv' does not exist
```

**FOLDER STRUCTURE**

```
Anconda
  env
    kmean.ipynb
    data
      walmart-stores.csv
    (other folders [for anaconda env])
 (other folders)
```

**QUESTION(S)**

1. The error clearly states that the csv file cannot be found. I imagine it has to do with the project running in an Anaconda environment, but I thought this was the purpose of Anaconda environments in the first place. Am I wrong?
2. After answering the question, **are there any other suggestions on how I should structure my Jupyter Notebooks when using Anaconda?**

*NOTES: I am new to python, anaconda, and jupyter notebooks so please disregard are naivety/stupidity. Thank you!*

Comment: Did you try changing it to ``data = pd.read_csv("data/walmart-stores.csv")``?

Comment: Also, you should probably not be working in the ``Anaconda/env`` directory. That is where Anaconda's installation artifacts are located; it's better practice to have your working directory elsewhere.

Comment: @jakevdp error with data = pd.read_csv("walmart-stores.csv"), looks like it's a utf-8 encoding issue. I'll research more to strip out any UTF-8 characters. Thanks!

Comment: Just add the encoding= "utf-8" to the read statement data = pd.read_csv("data/walmart-stores.csv",encoding= "utf-8" )

Answer (score 0):

Fellow newbie here!
Try removing the "../" from your data location

Change

```
data = pd.read_csv("../data/walmart-stores.csv")
```

to

```
data = pd.read_csv("data/walmart-stores.csv")
```